# PHP ERROR Auto-Include width/height tags for images

Tags: php, css, http

Please help to improve.
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool  on line 168

```html
if ($this->output) {
    //Q: Add width/height tags to all images for Google Page Speed tip:
    //http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#SpecifyImageDimensions
               preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $this->output, $result);
               $img = array();
               foreach($result[0] as $img_tag) {
                   preg_match_all('/(width|height|src)=("[^"]*")/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
               }
               foreach ($img as $k => $info) {
                   if (count($info) == 3 && isset($info[1][0]) && $info[1][0] == 'src') {
                   //if (curl_init(str_replace('"', '', $info[2][0]))) {
                   $imgfile = str_replace('"', '', $info[2][0]);
                   $imgfile = str_replace(HTTP_SERVER, DIR_IMAGE . '../', $imgfile);
                   $imgfile = str_replace(HTTPS_SERVER, DIR_IMAGE . '../', $imgfile);
                       if (file_exists($imgfile)) {
                           $image_info = getImageSize(str_replace('"', '', $imgfile));
                       $k = trim($k, '/>');
167                    $k = trim($k, '>');
168                    $this->output = str_replace($k, ($k . ' ' . $image_info[3]), $this->output);
```

Comment: The function `getImageSize` returns `false` on failure.

Comment: What need change?

Comment: You need to test the return value of `getimagesize` to see if it is `false`. You should also make sure that PHP error reporting is turned on so that you can see what the problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to provide test like that.

Comment: `if(false === $image_info){/*do something here*/}`